# Crash in Aviary SDK after integrating Google Analytics

Tags: ios, aviary

Recently I have integrated the Google Analytics framework in my `iOS` app . Before integration the Aviary is working fine but now Aviary is not working properly . I am using `xcode 5` . The error is

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AFPhotoEditorCustomization setEditorSettingsDefaults]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc2164a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x03c2b5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02e338b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x03cc8903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x03c1b90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x03c1b4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   VerizonCaseCustomizer               0x0022f436 -[AFPhotoEditorCustomization initWithDictionary:] + 192
    6   VerizonCaseCustomizer               0x0022effb +[AFPhotoEditorCustomization options] + 198
    7   VerizonCaseCustomizer               0x0022f32a +[AFPhotoEditorCustomization optionValueForKey:] + 58
    8   VerizonCaseCustomizer               0x00222f16 +[AFLocalization isLocalizationDisabled] + 49
    9   VerizonCaseCustomizer               0x001feaa1 AFLocalizedString + 52
    10  VerizonCaseCustomizer               0x001c118d -[AFSDKViewController viewDidLoad] + 113
    11  UIKit                               0x007209a8 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    12  UIKit                               0x00720c44 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    13  VerizonCaseCustomizer               0x0008ec37 -[verizonlibrary displayPhotoEditorWithImage:] + 2247
    14  VerizonCaseCustomizer               0x0008def9 -[verizonlibrary facebookimageslater:] + 905
    15  Foundation                          0x0285d36c __NSFireDelayedPerform + 372
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x03be9c46 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x03be962d __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1181
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x03bd1698 __CFRunLoopRun + 1816
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x03bd0b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x03bd094b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x03b879d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x03b877fe GSEventRun + 104
    23  UIKit                               0x0060d94b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    24  VerizonCaseCustomizer               0x0000611f main + 79
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0689970d start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Please let me know if I am not clear . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

set -ObjC -all_load to other linker flags from build settings

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the -force_load flag in other linker flags. You would do that by including the following in your other linker flags:

`-force_load /path/to/AviarySDK.framework`

Answer (score 0):

`Add linker flags`

Update your target's (or project's) `build settings` to include the following `"Other Linker Flags"`:

`-ObjC`
`-all_load`

Like this:
[image]